# Unity3D gui button inside gui window error

Tags: button, user-interface, window, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem with a gui button inside a dragable gui window. In my scene i have a cube, and when i click it, it opens a window. inside the window there's a button to upgrade the cube. The problem is, when the window opens, the upgrade buttons code plays automatically as if it had been inside the update function.

I have the exact same code inside 2 other scripts where it works perfectly.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

I have really no idea where i could have done something wrong, so here's the code i believe is relevant, if it's not enough please let me know and i'll provide more information :)

Here's the code:

```
function Upgrade ()
{
    var price : float;
    price = (level * 400) + 400;

    if (budget > price)
    {
        level++;
        budget -= price;
        maxStorage += 10;
        Debug.LogWarning("Upgraded to level " + level);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Upgrade failed. Not enough money.");
    }
}

function OnGUI ()
{

    if (windowOpen == true)
    {
        windowRect = GUI.Window (windowId, windowRect, WindowFunction, "Statistics Industry");
    }
    if (tooltip != "")
    {
        GUI.BeginGroup (new Rect (25, Screen.height - 125, 200, 100));
        GUI.Box (new Rect (0, 0, 200, 100), "");

            GUI.Label (Rect (15, 15, 170, 70), tooltip);

        GUI.EndGroup();
    }

}
function WindowFunction (windowID : int) 
{
    GUI.Label (Rect (25, 25, 175, 30), "Location: " + cityName);
    GUI.Label (Rect (25, 50, 175, 30), "Budget: " + budget);
    GUI.Label (Rect (25, 75, 175, 30), "Storage: " + storage + " / " + maxStorage);
    GUI.Label (Rect (25, 100, 175, 30), "Energy: " + Mathf.Round(energy));
    GUI.Label (Rect (25, 125, 175, 30), "Tax: " + taxPercent + "%");

    //goods price pr unit
    GUI.Label (Rect (25, 150, 175, 30), "Price for goods.");
    sellPrice = GUI.HorizontalSlider (Rect (25, 181, 100, 15), sellPrice, 0.0, 10.0);
    GUI.Label (Rect (135, 175, 75, 30), "price: " + sellPrice.ToString("0.0"));
    //Create help button
    GUI.Button (new Rect (155, 150, 25, 25), GUIContent("?", "This is the price which the Industry will take for each piece of Material. \nSelling to Market."));
    //Display the tooltip
    if (Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint)
    {
        tooltip = GUI.tooltip;
    }

    //energy price pr unit
    GUI.Label (Rect (25, 200, 175, 30), "Price for energy.");
    energyPrice = GUI.HorizontalSlider (Rect (25, 231, 100, 15), energyPrice, 0.0, 10.0);
    GUI.Label (Rect (135, 225, 75, 30), "price: " + energyPrice.ToString("0.0"));
    //Create help button
    GUI.Button (new Rect (155, 200, 25, 25), GUIContent("?", "This is the price which the Industry will pay for each piece of Energy. \nBuying from Consumer."));
    //Display the tooltip
    if (Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint)
    {
        tooltip = GUI.tooltip;
    }
    //Upgrade button
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (25, 250, 150, 25), "Upgrade " + "(" + level + ")"));
    {
        Upgrade();
    }

    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (25, 280, 150, 25), "Close"))
    {
        renderer.material.mainTexture = mainTexture;
        windowOpen = false;
    }
    GUI.DragWindow (Rect (0,0,10000,10000));
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic 
because it is a simple typo, and this question is not helpful to future visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out that i had a semicolon at the end of my "if (GUI.Button ..." which my game didn't like :)